# The Twelve Bells missing beer style

Tags: fiz

I'm stuck at getting Banshee's Tear, now I know that there are 23 competitors for every style, except one. But I only have 23 styles, is there anything I'm missing? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

There are 24 different Beer Styles in Fiz. The 23 shown on the competition report for the Twelve Bells simply *doesn't list* one of them, and it's highly probable, at this point in the game, that you *do* have a recipe for it, and you just need to spot it in your list. Make a single beer of the missing style, and you'll complete the challenge. (Hurry though! The missing beer changes monthly!)

If, by some odd fluke, you *do* only have 23 of the styles available to you, you'll need to learn more recipes; the easiest way to do this is to keep brewing other stuff and *smashing mice*. You'll gain Recipe fragments that you can use to learn new brews.

Also, if you have any other open events, complete them. Some will award recipes!

Answer (score 2):

Every month, there is one beer type missing from the competition list. But that changes every month, so you'll have to go through the list of beer types that Fiz has and see which one's missing, and hope that you can make and sell it that month.

Here are the 24 types of beer that Fiz has:

- Amber
- American Wheat
- Barleywine
- Belgian Blonde Ale
- Belgian Wit
- Brown Ale
- Doppelbock
- Dunkel
- German Pilsner
- Hefeweizen
- Helles
- Imperial IPA
- IPA
- Irish Red Ale
- Lager
- Maibock
- Oktoberfest
- Pale Ale
- Porter
- Rauchbier
- Russian Imperial Stout
- Saison
- Special Bitter
- Stout

One beer type will be missing from the above list. Sell that beer to the Banshee and you're good to go. It would probably be helpful to buy the speediest equipment you can and dump craft points for your batch into speed.